# DataMaps - How to change the colour of the ocean

Tags: javascript, datamaps

https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps has a very nice javascript vector map, but it doesn't seem to have an option to change the colour of the ocean. I do however see that some of the demos have a different colour for the ocean. How can I change the colour of the ocean?

Comment: How about changing the background colour of the `svg` using `css`?

Comment: How do you change the background colour of the svg using css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the background colour of the target element. For instance if your div has the id 'data-map':

```
<div id="data-map"></div>
```

And you initiate the map like:

```
var datamap = new Datamap({
  element: document.getElementById("data-map")
});
```

Because the svg is transparent you can change the background colour of the div. This will make the 'oceans' that colour:

```
#data-map {
    background-color: #F00; //red
}
```

Comment: @foreyez setting a fill style on the path with class `datamaps-graticule` gets you there a little. Another option could be to make the svg a square and somehow the same size as the path. Then you can use `border-radius:50%` to create a circle, and fill the background of the svg

Comment: meh.. I ended up just sticking an svg circle (where its fill is set to ocean color) behind the orthographic map. works a treat. :>

Comment: @foreyez yes.. makes more sense :D